# Select query with MySQL database where distinct member id with least registration time are to be selected... How can I do it?

Tags: mysql, select, join, distinct

I am trying to work on a query where my database schema looks like:

```
MEMBER TABLE

member_id----------member_name--------member_nickname

    1              prashant             prash
    2              christopher          chris
    3              nick                 nick
    4              harvey               harvey

----------------------------------------------------------

CHECKIN TABLE

checkin_id------------------member_id------------------reg_on

    1                      1             1287713712
    2                      1             1287723999
    3                      2             1287733712
    4                      1             1287735912
    5                      3             1287803712
    6                      2             1287833712
```

Now when I select distinct users, I want to join both tables to see the following result:

```
member_id----------------member_name---------------reg_on

   1------------------------------prashant -----------------1287713712

   2------------------------------christopher---------------1287733712

   3------------------------------nick------------------------1287803712
```

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** Don't know what I was thinking by overcomplicating my previous answer...

This is a simple `JOIN` with an aggregate:

```
SELECT
  m.member_id,
  m.member_name,
  MIN(c.reg_on) AS reg_on
FROM
  MEMBER m JOIN CHECKIN c ON m.member_id = c.member_id
GROUP BY m.member_id, m.member_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `select` and `group by` the checkin table, that will give you the data you want, then `join` to the member table to fill out the rest of the query.

```
SELECT c.member_id, m.member_name, MIN(c.reg_on) AS reg_on
FROM checkin c
   JOIN member m ON m.member_id = c.member_id
GROUP BY c.reg_on
ORDER BY c.member_id;
```

No subselect necessary.

Comment: ...and I was slow. My answer is equivalent to Michael's.